# How to pass a csv file in 'Examples' in Feature file and read values from CSV file in Java cucumber

Tags: java, cucumber-serenity

1. In Cucumber 'Feature file '-> 'Examples' , how to set path for CSV file.

**Sample.feature**

```
    Feature:Launch an app 
    Scenario Outline:Validation of the application
        Given User navigates to application
        When User logs in using valid appname '<Name>'
    Examples:    
        @sources:src/test/resources/data_tables/temp.csv
        | Name |
```

**Junit Runner:**

```
package definitions;
import net.serenitybdd.cucumber.CucumberWithSerenity;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CucumberWithSerenity.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features/Sample.feature" )
public class AcceptanceTestSuite{   

}
```

Used CSV file

```
**temp.csv**
    name,
    Google,
```

But I didnt retrieve values from temp.csv file, result was 0 Scenarios
0 Steps
0m0.000s

2.Also wanted to know in Java Cucumber with Serenity, how to readvalues from CSV file that is mentioned in Feature file.